# Writing cypher query for traversing the path

Tags: neo4j

I am new to Neo4j.

I am using this query to get the below layout in traversing the path in first image:

[image: first image]

Code:

```
MATCH p = (r:Reports)<--(s:Schedules)<--(m:MDRMs)<--(br:Business_Requirements)-->(rp: Report_Logic)-->(ra: Reporting_layer_attributes)
where r.Report_Name ='FFIEC 031' and s.Schedule = 'RC-B - Securities' RETURN p
```

Blue coloured nodes are referred as Business_Requirements which have additional linked Silver coloured (Business_Attributes) nodes with relationship as MAPPED_TO.

How can I bring out the below layout through cypher query. Since the silver color nodes are not in the path, I was not able to pull the below required layout in the second image:

[image: second image]

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the `MATCH` by adding a second path p2, and including it in the `RETURN`

```
MATCH p = (r:Reports)<--(s:Schedules)<--(m:MDRMs)<--(br:Business_Requirements)-->(rp: Report_Logic)-->(ra: Reporting_layer_attributes),
      p2 = (br)<-[:MAPPED_TO]-(ba:Business_Attributes)

where r.Report_Name ='FFIEC 031' and s.Schedule = 'RC-B - Securities' 
RETURN p,p2
```

in case the MAPPED_TO rel is not always there, you can also use the OPTIONAL MATCH

```
MATCH p = (r:Reports)<--(s:Schedules)<--(m:MDRMs)<--(br:Business_Requirements)-->(rp: Report_Logic)-->(ra: Reporting_layer_attributes)
where r.Report_Name ='FFIEC 031' and s.Schedule = 'RC-B - Securities' 
OPTIONAL MATCH p2 = (br)<-[MAPPED_TO]-(ba:Business_Attributes)
```

RETURN p,p2

Comment: Prasanth, do Business_Requirements alway have at least one business_attributes? If yes, then this answer will work. But if Business_Requirements can have NO business attribute, then this query will fail.

Comment: added the OPTIONAL option to cover that case.